# Invalid Cat Exception

Tags: c#

I am trying to 'grab' the ID field (PK) from a database after data has been entered to it. Once I get the ID, I want to input it into another table (for relationship purposes). However, my attempts are unsuccessful.

This is what I'm currently doing:

```
int CompanyID;  

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=******;Initial Catalog= ********");
SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();

con.Open();

cmd.CommandText = "insert into [Company Information] (Expo_Year, Partnership, Company_Name_Pub, Address_Pub, City_Pub, State_Pub, Zip_Pub, Phone_Pub, Fax_Pub, Email_Pub, Contact_Pub, Company_Name_Ex, Address_Ex, City_Ex, State_Ex, Zip_Ex, Phone_Ex, Fax_Ex, Email_Ex, Contact_Ex) VALUES (@Year, @Partnership,@PubCompanyName,@PubAddress,@PubCity,@PubState,@PubZip,@PubPhone,@PubFax,@PubEmail,@PubContact,@ExCompanyName,@ExAddress,@ExCity,@ExState,@ExZip,@ExPhone,@ExFax,@ExEmail,@ExContact) SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();";

SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
param.ParameterName = "@PubCompanyName";
param.Value = CompanyNmTxt.Text;

cmd.Parameters.Add("@Year", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = Year.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Partnership", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = DropDownList1.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@PubCompanyName", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar,50).Value = CompanyNmTxt.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@PubAddress", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar,50).Value = CompanyAddTxt.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@PubCity", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar,50).Value = CompanyCtyTxt.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@PubState", System.Data.SqlDbType.Char,2).Value = StateDD.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@PubZip", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int,8).Value = CompanyZipTxt.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@PubPhone", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar,50).Value = CompanyPhoneTxt.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@PubFax", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar,50).Value = CompanyFaxTxt.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@PubEmail", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar,50).Value = CompanyEmailTxt.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@PubContact", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar,50).Value = CompanyContactTxt.Text;

cmd.Parameters.Add("@ExCompanyName", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = ExCompanyNmTxt0.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ExAddress", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = ExCompanyAddTxt0.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ExCity", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = ExCompanyCtyTxt0.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ExState", System.Data.SqlDbType.Char, 2).Value = ExStateDD.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ExZip", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 8).Value = ExCompanyZipTxt0.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ExPhone", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = ExCompanyPhoneTxt0.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ExFax", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = ExCompanyFaxTxt0.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ExEmail", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = ExCompanyEmailTxt0.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ExContact", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = ExCompanyContactTxt0.Text;

CompanyID = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar(); 
con.Close();
```

I get the error:

> InvalidCastException was unhandeled by user code; Specified cast is not valid.

Comment: What is it about a Cat that makes it invalid I wonder?  It seems like there should be an appropriate LOLcat for this, but I know of none.

Comment: a question with that title already exists

Comment: Build a try-catch-block around your code and take a look at the exception-object.

Comment: Which line is the error on?

Comment: Barmar, the error is on the CompanyID = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar(); portion.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious things that stick out to me are that you're storing zip codes as integers. They really should be strings (since leading zeros are valid). This line might be a culprit:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@PubZip", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int,8).Value = CompanyZipTxt.Text;
```

You might want to try something along the lines of:

```
int companyZip;
Int32.TryParse(CompanyZipTxt.Text, out companyZip);

cmd.Parameters.Add("@PubZip", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 8).Value = companyZip;
```

You also have a couple of other lines with similar issues.

Comment: I changed that; thanks for that tip. I'm still getting the same error though. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user2117049: One other thing to consider is that you're performing an insert operation which is a `Nonquery` rather than a `Scalar`. It might be helpful if you switch to `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation for ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx):

> Return Value Type: System.Object The first column of the first row in
>   the result set, or a null reference (Nothing in Visual Basic) if the
>   result set is empty. Returns a maximum of 2033 characters.

What's in the first column of your table?  (Presumably, it's your CompanyId column.)  Is it a uniqueId?  That would cast to a Guid, not an int.

Comment: The end of the query is `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` which will be an int, not a GUID.

Comment: Fair enough... but at least in T-SQL, the response type of SCOPE_IDENTITY is numeric(38,0), which wouldn't be castable to an int.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx

Comment: Scott, Thanks for the reply. The first column is "ID". I have it set as the PK and int.

Comment: The best I can recommend then is that you just grab the result with `var temp = cmd.ExecuteScalar();`, set a breakpoint on that line, and see what type is being returned.  Somewhere, something isn't coming out as an int.

Comment: Also, in whatever way you have to interact with SQL, make sure that if you enter the row manually, you get the result you expect.

Comment: It seems there is a problem with grabbing the ID field from the table. I checked, and the value it is grabbing is 0.

Comment: Okay, I finally got it working. I added , "SELECT ID FROM [Company Information] WHERE ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()" to the query. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Nice.  That way you made SQL convert the `numeric(38,0)` to an `int` for you, and eliminated the exception.  Good job!